# why oracle database not storing table values?

Tags: database, oracle, netbeans, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am learning database. I have installed Oracle 12c in windows. Then i have created some tables, i have read the tables values and have done some basic operations. I have created about 12 tables. Now my problem is if i am creating any new table then it is showing that the table has created successfully. And insertion of Data is working. Now if i am creating and inserting data from sqlplus, in the SqlDevelopper and in the netbeans IDE it is only showing the table name but no data and sometimes not even showing the table name, though i have refreshed. And after closing the sqlplus and opening it again if i am trying  to retrieve the data, it is showing that no row has selected. But the describe command in sql showing that there exist a table.

And if i am creating  a  new table in SQL-Developper and inserting data there, after restarting the  SQLDevelopper, it is only showing the table name but no data.And the table is not showing in netbeans or SQlPlus.

Please anyone tell me how can i solve this.

Comment: Let me guess... you start a transaction and never commit it?

Comment: sorry what is it "commit"?

Comment: You need some basics on [transactions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm)

Comment: Ok  give me down vote but at least tell me how i can solve this..

Comment: To tell you what you're doing wrong we need your code, not a vague description of your tools. But if you don't know what a transaction is I recommend you first find a book or tutorial on basic SQL.

Comment: Yes i dont know transaction..i learned only insert,delete,join,update..

Comment: I just gave a link to start from;  Álvaro González suggested to study COMMIT, so you can even search the net for something like "SQL COMMIT". In this way you should find some good points to start studying transactions

Comment: @ Aleksej ..ok i am  doing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you don't know about Transaction,for this moment as a solution just type the "commit" command after completing the insertion. And do some study on "Transaction". Hope this might help you.

Details have given below:

**First what is transaction?**

**Ans:**

Often, several operations on the database form a single logical unit of work. An
example is a funds transfer.Let consider a university which has many departments. Each depart has fund, now you want to transfer fund of one’s department to another department ,in which one department account (say A) is debited and another department account (say B) is credited.

**Clearly,** it is essential that either both the credit and debit occur, or that neither occur. That is, the funds transfer must happen in its entirety or not at all. This all-or-none requirement is called **atomicity.**

In addition, it is essential that the execution of the funds transfer preserve the consistency of the database. That is, the value of the sum of the balances of A and B must be preserved. This correctness requirement is called **consistency.**

**Finally,** after the successful execution of a funds transfer, the new values of the balances of accounts A and B must persist, despite the possibility of system failure. This persistence requirement is called durability.

A transaction is a collection of operations that performs a single logical
function in a database application. Each transaction is a unit of both **atomicity** and **consistency**. Thus, we require that transactions do not violate any database consistency constraints. That is, if the database was consistent when a transaction started, the database must be consistent when the transaction successfully terminates. However, during the execution of a transaction, it may be necessary temporarily to allow inconsistency, since either the debit of A or the credit of B must be done before the other. This temporary inconsistency, although necessary, may lead to difficulty if a failure occurs.

It is the programmer’s responsibility to define properly the various transactions, so that each preserves the consistency of the database. For example, the transaction to transfer funds from the account of department A to the account of
department B could be defined to be composed of two separate programs: one
that debits account A, and another that credits account B. The execution of these
two programs one after the other will indeed preserve consistency. However, each
program by itself does not transform the database from a consistent state to a new
consistent state. Thus, those programs are not transactions.

Ensuring the atomicity and durability properties is the responsibility of the
database system itself—specifically, of the recovery manager. In the absence of
failures, all transactions complete successfully, and atomicity is achieved easily.
However, because of various types of failure, a transaction may not always complete its execution successfully. If we are to ensure the atomicity property, a failed transaction must have no effect on the state of the database. 
Thus, the database must be restored to the state in which it was before the transaction in question started executing. The database system must there foreper form failure recovery, that is, detect system failures and restore the database to the state that existed prior to the occurrence of the failure.

Finally, when several transactions update the database concurrently, the consistency of data may no longer be preserved, even though each individual transaction is correct. It is the responsibility of the concurrency-control manager to control the interaction among the concurrent transactions, to ensure the consistency of the database. The transaction manager consists of the concurrency-control manager and the recovery manager. The concept of a transaction has been applied broadly in database systems and applications. While the initial use of transactions was in financial applications, the concept is now used in real-time applications in telecommunication, as well as in the management of long-duration activities such as product design or administrative workflows.

**Now transaction in SQL:**

Transaction Control:

There are following commands used to control transactions:

```
COMMIT: to save the changes.

ROLLBACK: to rollback the changes.

SAVEPOINT: creates points within groups of transactions in which to ROLLBACK

SET TRANSACTION: Places a name on a transaction.
```

Transactional control commands are only used with the DML commands INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE only. They can not be used while creating tables or dropping them because these operations are automatically commited in the database.

The COMMIT Command:

The COMMIT command is the transactional command used to save changes invoked by a transaction to the database.

The COMMIT command saves all transactions to the database since the last COMMIT or ROLLBACK command.

The syntax for COMMIT command is as follows:

```
COMMIT;
```

Example:

Consider the CUSTOMERS table having the following records:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Following is the example which would delete records from the table having age = 25 and then COMMIT the changes in the database.

```
SQL> DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS
     WHERE AGE = 25;
SQL> COMMIT;
```

As a result, two rows from the table would be deleted and SELECT statement would produce the following result:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

The ROLLBACK Command:

The ROLLBACK command is the transactional command used to undo transactions that have not already been saved to the database.

The ROLLBACK command can only be used to undo transactions since the last COMMIT or ROLLBACK command was issued.

The syntax for ROLLBACK command is as follows:

```
ROLLBACK;
```

Example:

Consider the CUSTOMERS table having the following records:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Following is the example, which would delete records from the table having age = 25 and then ROLLBACK the changes in the database.

```
SQL> DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS
     WHERE AGE = 25;
SQL> ROLLBACK;
```

As a result, delete operation would not impact the table and SELECT statement would produce the following result:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------
```

The SAVEPOINT Command:

A SAVEPOINT is a point in a transaction when you can roll the transaction back to a certain point without rolling back the entire transaction.

The syntax for SAVEPOINT command is as follows:

```
SAVEPOINT SAVEPOINT_NAME;
```

This command serves only in the creation of a SAVEPOINT among transactional statements. The ROLLBACK command is used to undo a group of transactions.

The syntax for rolling back to a SAVEPOINT is as follows:

```
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT_NAME;
```

Following is an example where you plan to delete the three different records from the CUSTOMERS table. You want to create a SAVEPOINT before each delete, so that you can ROLLBACK to any SAVEPOINT at any time to return the appropriate data to its original state:

Example:

Consider the CUSTOMERS table having the following records:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Now, here is the series of operations:

```
SQL> SAVEPOINT SP1;
Savepoint created.
SQL> DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ID=1;
1 row deleted.
SQL> SAVEPOINT SP2;
Savepoint created.
SQL> DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ID=2;
1 row deleted.
SQL> SAVEPOINT SP3;
Savepoint created.
SQL> DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ID=3;
1 row deleted.
```

Now that the three deletions have taken place, say you have changed your mind and decided to ROLLBACK to the SAVEPOINT that you identified as SP2. Because SP2 was created after the first deletion, the last two deletions are undone:

```
SQL> ROLLBACK TO SP2;
Rollback complete.
```

Notice that only the first deletion took place since you rolled back to SP2:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
6 rows selected.
```

The RELEASE SAVEPOINT Command:

The RELEASE SAVEPOINT command is used to remove a SAVEPOINT that you have created.

The syntax for RELEASE SAVEPOINT is as follows:

```
RELEASE SAVEPOINT SAVEPOINT_NAME;
```

Once a SAVEPOINT has been released, you can no longer use the ROLLBACK command to undo transactions performed since the SAVEPOINT.
The SET TRANSACTION Command:

The SET TRANSACTION command can be used to initiate a database transaction. This command is used to specify characteristics for the transaction that follows.

For example, you can specify a transaction to be read only, or read write.

The syntax for SET TRANSACTION is as follows:

```
SET TRANSACTION [ READ WRITE | READ ONLY ];
```

So now if want to see the changes that you have made from net-beans to sql-plus, you have use the commit command and vice versa. One thing is that in sql-plus if you just close the `sqlplus` window, then it will be automatically rolled back to its starting position and if don't use `commit` command but just type `exit` to come out from `sqlplus`, then it will automatically be committed. But don't do this, it is a bad practice.